# List of all file command outputs?

Tags: documentation, file-command

The `file -b <path>` command seems useful for scripting (filtering file types, not necessarily by extension). But for that you have to know the actual string output for your target filetype(s)

If I want to match certain file types, but don't have all of them handy, is there a list of all the possible outputs?

I found docs for the [magic file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) - using `cat /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc | grep -a 'pattern'` sort of works, but it's awkward and you have to know exactly what you're looking for.

is there any **documentation of the recognized file types** somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your best best would be to look at https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `man file` and use `file -l`.
`file` inspect the first few bytes of a file to determine the "type". Note that Unix/Linux filenames treat "extensions" as just part of the filename. The use of the ".ext" extensions are just tradition, not a requirement.

Comment: "The use of the ".ext" extensions are just tradition, not a requirement." - there were loose conventions around this but it was a hard requirement in the early versions of MS-Windows. But I have no idea why this was downvoted, `file -l` exactly answers the questions asked

Comment: `file -l` seems like exactly what I was looking for! thanks